# How to use Intent.ACTION_VIEW for image for document URI?

Tags: android

I have a document URI for image (Android 9), for example:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2F2cats.jpg
```

Is it possible to open default app for view the image?

Standard method is not work:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType( uri, "image/*");
    startActivity( intent );
```

Convert URI to file by `getContentResolver().query` is not work too.

Comment: Yes that is possible if the permission for that uri is still valid. Add a flag Intent.FLAG_GRAND_READ_URI_PERMISSION.

Comment: @blackapps Please convert it to answer, I will accept it (only FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible if the permission for that uri is still valid.

Add a flag

```
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION.
```